# Is Mongodb geohaystack the same with standard mongodb spatial index?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

It seems that mongodb has 2 types of geospatial index.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing

The standard one. With a note:

> You may only have 1 geospatial index per collection, for now. While
>   MongoDB may allow to create multiple indexes, this behavior is
>   unsupported. Because MongoDB can only use one index to support a
>   single query, in most cases, having multiple geo indexes will produce
>   undesirable behavior.

And then there is this so called geohaystack thingy.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Haystack+Indexing

They both claim to use the same algorithm. They both turn earth into several grids. And then search based on that.

So what's the different?

Mongodb doesn't seem to use Rtree and stuff right?

NB: Answer to this question that [How does MongoDB implement it's spatial indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492065/how-does-mongodb-implement-its-spatial-indexes/12494924#12494924) says that 2d index use geohash too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation is similar, but the use case difference is described on the [Geospatial Haystack Indexing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Haystack+Indexing) page.

The haystack indices are "bucket-based" (aka "quadrant") searches tuned for small-region longitude/latitude searches:

```
    In addition to ordinary 2d geospatial indices, mongodb supports the use
    of bucket-based geospatial indexes. Called "Haystack indexing", these
    indices can accelerate small-region type longitude / latitude queries
    when additional criteria is also required.

    For example, "find all restaurants within 25 miles with name 'foo'".

    Haystack indices allow you to tune your bucket size to the distribution
    of your data, so that in general you search only very small regions of
    2d space for a particular kind of document.  They are not suited for
    finding the closest documents to a particular location, when the
    closest documents are far away compared to bucket size.
```

The `bucketSize` parameter is required, and determines the granularity of the haystack index.

So, for example:

```
 db.places.ensureIndex({ pos : "geoHaystack", type : 1 }, { bucketSize : 1 })
```

This example bucketSize of 1 creates an index where keys within 1 unit of longitude or latitude are stored in the same bucket.  An additional category can also be included in the index, which means that information will be looked up at the same time as finding the location details.

The B-tree representation would be similar to:

```
 { loc: "x,y", category: z }
```

If your use case typically searches for "nearby" locations (i.e. "restaurants within 25 miles") a haystack index can be more efficient.  The matches for the additional indexed field (eg. category) can be found and counted within each bucket.

If, instead, you are searching for "nearest restaurant" and would like to return results regardless of distance, a normal 2d index will be more efficient.

There are currently (as of MongoDB 2.2.0) a few limitations on haystack indexes:

- only one additional field can be included in the haystack index
- the additional index field has to be a single value, not an array
- null long/lat values are not supported

Note: distance between degrees of latitude will vary greatly (longitude, less so).  See: [What is the distance between a degree of latitude and longitude?](http://geography.about.com/library/faq/blqzdistancedegree.htm).

Comment: The haystack is bucket base, and the normal one is not? I know the normal one is not r-tree right?

Comment: @JimThio: The default 2d implementation is actually B-tree based.  At least one person is working on an R-Tree implementation to contribute ([SERVER-3551](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3551)) but this doesn't appear to have eventuated in a pull request yet.  There is a recent presentation from MongoDC contrasting B-Tree with R-Tree which suggests he has made progress: [RTree Spatial Indexing with MongoDB](http://www.slideshare.net/nknize/rtree-spatial-indexing-with-mongodb-mongodc).

Comment: @JimThio .. further to this, the contributor working on R-Tree is actually a 10gen partner and has several commercial offerings available: [Getting to Know Geospatial and MongoDB with TST](http://t-sciences.com/geospatial_and_mongodb.php).

Comment: @JimThio: I've revised my answer to (hopefully) make it a bit clearer that the haystack index is more of a specific use case optimization than an entirely different implementation.  The haystack index is certainly less documented (and probably as a consequence less commonly used).  Eventually it would probably make sense to merge this functionality into the main geospatial index.  There are also other geospatial algorithms that could be implemented with broader geo support than [GeoHash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) and remove the need for this specific use case optimization.

Comment: @JimThio: In terms of "bucket-based", the usage here is referring to the broader precision selected for a haystack index as well as the use case optimization. When [creating a 2d index](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-CreatingtheIndex) you can also specify bits of precision as well as index bounds. By default, 2d precision is set to 26 bits which is equivalent to approximately 2 feet given (longitude, latitude) location values and default (-180, 180) bounds. The two geospatial index types here are currently similar (but not identical) implementations.

Comment: I see. By the way is it optimal to use 26 bits of 2d precision? The reason in normal indexing if you search for 5<x<6, for example, when you reach number 7 you know that anything above it will be excluded. What about for 2d?

Comment: This says that mongodb regular 2d indexes use geohash too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492065/how-does-mongodb-implement-its-spatial-indexes/12494924#12494924

Comment: @JimThio: Yes, I did mention that regular 2d indexes use GeoHash  algorithm (and both 2d and haystack are using B-tree).  The GeoHaystack indexes make more assumptions for optimizing the specific use case of "near" geo search cases .. will see if I can find a more specific reference for the algorithm.