# How does MongoDB implement it's spatial indexes?

Tags: mongodb

> The current implementation encodes geographic hash codes atop standard
>   MongoDB B-trees. Results of $near queries are exact. One limitation
>   with this encoding, while fast, is that prefix lookups don't give
>   exact results, especially around bit flip areas.  MongoDB solves this
>   by doing a grid-neighbor search after the initial prefix scan to pick
>   up any straggler points.  This generally ensures that performance
>   remains very high while providing correct results.

Does that mean mongodb split the earth into several grids?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This presentation from Greg Studer (10gen) discusses the geospatial indexes in some detail:
 [Geospatial Indexing with MongoDB](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/geospatial-indexing-with-mongodb).

The standard geospatial implementation as at MongoDB 2.2 uses a 2-D [GeoHash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) approach, with variable bits of precision:

```
By default, precision is set to 26 bits which is equivalent to approximately
2 feet given (longitude, latitude) location values and default (-180, 180)
bounds.
```

The GeoHash approach does have edge cases where some points may be spatially close but have different hashes.  MongoDB also includes a [Geospatial Haystack Index](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Haystack+Indexing) which is specifically tuned for small-region "near" long/lat searches with one additional indexed criteria (for example: "find all restaurants within 25 miles with name 'foo'").

Another interesting presentation from Nicholas Knize (Thermopylae) contrasts the current B-tree / GeoHash approach with [R-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).  If you skip ahead to slide 8, there is a visual explanation that may be helpful:
 [RTree Spatial Indexing with MongoDB - MongoDC](http://www.slideshare.net/nknize/rtree-spatial-indexing-with-mongodb-mongodc).

Comment: link broken i.e. geospatial indexing with MongoDB